# How to retrieve discharge summaries?

Tags: mimic-iii

How can I get the discharge summaries in mimic III, I tried putting 'Summary' as a category but didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try `Discharge summary`:

```
select  category, count(*) 
from mimiciii.noteevents 
group by category 
order by category asc;
```

[image]